# unix move cursor after last character

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix

After I use my arrow key to move my cursor left, I am unable to move it back to the end of the line. For instance:

If I type:

```
$ echo hello wordl_
```

Then if I move the cursor left to fix typo

```
$ echo hello wor_l
```

I am unable to move the cursor back to the end of the line and the `"l"` will remain.  So I then have to enter vi mode `ESC,right, a` to get to the end of the line.  I am on a mac and bash is my shell.

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Am I the only one who has this problem??

Comment: Seems like you use vi mode. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105721/how-to-move-to-end-of-line-in-vim

Comment: @Evert Thanks `ESC, A` is useful.  But I'd rather not have to `ESC` or use a 3 key combo.  I was on someone's terminal once and didn't have this issue

Comment: @jermel well, the other person whose terminal you used probably wasn't using vi mode. It's not an "issue", it's a preference. Maybe you set it by mistake? Check your `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: @Celada well done, could you post your comment as an answer so the question can be marked as answered please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *feature* of using vi key bindings `set -o vi`. To solve my problem I switched to emacs key bindings

```
$ set -o emacs
```

Comment: Yeah but then you have to use emacs bindings :)